# Nginx Reverse Proxy Redirect Issues

Tags: redirect, nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy, http-proxy

I have been struggling with this for some time now. My reverse proxy install essentially looks like this:

global_nginx: http://192.168.115.200/client1/ => docker_nginx: http://localhost:8877/ => docker_app: http://app:8080/

Reverse proxy is working fine, but I have trouble when my app is sending redirects. Essentially the app itself is just a Spring MVC application that redirects as following:

```
@Controller
public class Ctrl {
    @RequestMapping(value = { "/" })
    public String redir() {
        return "redirect:home";
    }
}
```

The result is that when I browse http://192.168.115.200/client1/ I am redirected to: http://192.168.115.200/home/ but should be redirected to http://192.168.115.200/client1/home/

This is the global_nginx conf:

```
location /client1 {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8877/.;
    proxy_redirect http://localhost:8877/ /;
    port_in_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
}
```

And this is my docker_nginx conf:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://app:8080/;
    proxy_redirect http://app:8080/ /;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the `/client1` prefix in your `proxy_redirect` directive.

Maybe:

```
proxy_redirect http://$host:8877/ /client1/;
```

You can have more than one `proxy_redirect` directive, if you need to match multiple conditions. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_redirect) for details.

Comment: Thanks I was missing the `/client1/` . But after I added this, it still kept failing. I ended up netcat-ing on the server to see the host portion of proxy-passed request. Global_nginx did not change the http request host portion from from `192.168.115.200 => localhost` as I had presumed. This gave me the idea to change the global_nginx proxy redirect to this that ended up working:
`proxy_redirect http://$host:8877/ /client1/;`